# Missing argument for parameter options in call in swift 2

Tags: swift

I Want to Execute countdown timer in swift 2 but it have a issue like Missing argument for parameter options, how to solve this, In swift 1.2 i execute the same code but in swift 2 i cant do it..

In swift 1.2

```
        let components1 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitSecond |
        .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitDay |
        .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: UTCDate,
        toDate: date!, options: nil)
```

In swift 2

```
let components1 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date!)
```

Here Where I want to give toDate in swift 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `options` parameter in Swift 2 for this method is not an optional anymore so you can't pass nil to it, you have to pass an empty array if you don't want to specify options:

```
let components1 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: UTCDate, toDate: date!, options: [])
```

Comment: Oh...it Works good....Thanks..@Eric D...